# Not able to save a record to the database and display flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I don't see any error messages but when checked in rails console I could figure out that no new object is saved. Also validations are working along with display of flash messages

This is my model:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
        validates :title, presence:true
        validates :description, presence: true
    end
```

Controller:

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @pin=Pin.new
  end

  def create

        @pin=Pin.new(pin_params)

        if @pin.save
            flash[:success] = 'Successfully saved your Pin'
            redirect_to @pin
        else
            flash[:danger] = 'Error occured'
            render @pin
        end
  end

private

    def pin_params

        params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description)
    end

end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pins

  root "pins#index"
end
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PinBoard</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<div>

    <div class = "top">
        <<p></p>
    </div>


    <div class= "container">
        <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <%= content_tag :div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}" %>
        <% end %>
        <%= yield %>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

logs:

```
Started GET "/pins/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=pBR0DfoMaWEAcK1i89t5wOhU%2BpFrbmEotW%2ByyDj6TJLfggMZ41wVKCrndjxWbjzZXbzQAHNrGS%2Bb7ncAlD%2BLxw%3D%3D&pin%5Btitle%5D=&pin%5Bdescription%5D=&commit=Create+Pin" for ::1 at 2016-12-08 20:07:25 -0600
Processing by PinsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pBR0DfoMaWEAcK1i89t5wOhU+pFrbmEotW+yyDj6TJLfggMZ41wVKCrndjxWbjzZXbzQAHNrGS+b7ncAlD+Lxw==", "pin"=>{"title"=>"", "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Pin"}
  Rendered pins/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 26.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="well">
            <form>

                <div class="form-group">    
                        <%=form_for @pin do |f| %>
                        <%= f.label :title %>
                        <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'%>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <%= f.label  :description %>
                        <%= f.text_area  :description, class: 'form-control'%>
                </div>

                <%= f.submit 'Create Pin', class: 'btn btn-default'%>

                <%end%>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: In that response the title is sending "" and the description is sending "", Do you see that? after the "pin"=>{ ... part. "  "pin"=>{"title"=>"", "description"=>""},"  So nothing is getting sent with the form, the data for those would be in there.  Can you post the form you are using?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Form is sending the details, in the previous response I submitted empty fields.                                                Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RUiIVVJzSAztV2ncGL9/O5PWPxojLvNUvp5AUYdv6ME+3v9BSyM0RcfAsoK9CjoiJj4Vizsri1OQH4WZK6ovlA==", "pin"=>{"title"=>"test", "description"=>"description"}, "commit"=>"Create Pin"}
  Rendered pins/new.html.erb within layouts/application (27.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 577ms (Views: 560.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

Comment: Use `save!` instead of `save`, you can easily get the error in logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You views/pins/_form.html.erb is wrong

Fix it:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="well">
      <%=form_for @pin do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :title %>
          <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'%>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label  :description %>
          <%= f.text_area  :description, class: 'form-control'%>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit 'Create Pin', class: 'btn btn-default'%>
      <%end%>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```